# Pthreads - why C functions are declared as void*?

Tags: c, pthreads

Example ([source](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables)):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The function is declared to return a void pointer, but there's no return statement in its body. What is going on here?

Generally if a function has been declared as returning a value (in this case, a void pointer) and there's no return statement, its behaviour is undefined.
Comments say that `pthread_exit(NULL)` is equivalent for calling `return NULL` - how can it be? You can call function `B()` from `A()` in such a way that `B()` calls return for `A`. Return statements refer to the function in which they are placed.

Comment: `pthread_exit` doesn't return to its caller.

Comment: That still leaves the question - why specify a void* return type?  Why not just void?

Comment: @JohnBollinger - what is it?

Comment: Oh - I'm guessing the return value can be accessed from another thread that waits for it  by calling pthread_join().

Comment: @MartinJames I was rtesponding to WeatherVane's comment, which he deleted (so I deleted my response).  Nevertheless, the difference between a `void` function and a `void *` function is that the latter returns a value (of type `void *`).  The former does not return any value at all.

Comment: Err, easy; A return from a non-**main** thread is equivalent to it invoking `pthread_exit()` with the `void*` return value. A return from the **main** thread (the one that invoked `int main()`) is equivalent to calling `exit()` with the `int` return value. As previously mentioned, `pthread_exit()` does not return in much the same way `exit()` doesn't. There is additional motivation for `pthread_exit`: If called from the **main** thread, instead of instantly causing an exit, the main thread waits for all others to exit and then calls `exit()`.

Comment: Calling `pthread_exit(NULL);` is equivalent to `return NULL;`. So your function do not have(do not need) a return statement.  Returning `void*` allows a thread to return a more useful & generic value than `void` or say `int`.

Comment: l repost my comment for clarity (I deleted it after noticing the function has a `*void` return value):: Following @n.m. comment, *in general* a `void` function returns after the last statement without a value, so there is no need to explicitly `return xxx`. The function might have needed to do an early `return` but here, it didn't, it exited the thread.

Comment: @BlueMoon, more specifically, calling `pthread_exit(NULL)` is equivalent to returning `NULL` *for the start function of a thread*.  That does appear to be the intended usage of the given function, but it is best to be clear that it is only in that context that the equivalence holds.

Answer (score 0):

We can only speculate about what may be going on, but since it looks like a "Hello, World!" program, a reasonable guess would be that a pointer to that function is intended to be passed to `pthread_create()`.  `pthread_create()` requires a pointer to a function having that signature.  It's a strange construction even so; it would be equivalent but clearer for the function to just return `NULL`.

Comment: I suspect pthread_join() may have something to do with it.  The docs are not 100% clear.

Comment: No, `pthread_join()` has nothing directly to do with it.  As I said, though, if the function is supposed to be the start function of a thread, then it needs to have the signature it does.  It is true, however, that the value passed to `pthread_exit()` (or returned by the function, if it didn't call `pthread_exit()`) is supplied to the caller of `pthread_join()`.

Comment: Well, if there was no pthread_join, there would be no need for a return type or for pthread_exit to take a parameter.

Comment: @MartinJames as a matter of the design of the `pthreads` library, maybe not.  If there were no `pthread_join()` then the signature of the `pthread_create()` would probably be different.  But it is the signature of `pthread_create()`, not anything directly related to `pthread_join()`, that determines the required signature for the start function of a thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'd say that design decision determines return type of a thread start function, and all those *pthread_xxx* functions are equally bound by that design decision, signatures determined by that.